# Android: calling a simple webservice method using ksoap2

Tags: android, ksoap2

I'm trying to call the method getWeather() of this webservice: http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx?WSDL

Here is my code:

```
public class ServiceCall {
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
private static final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.com/globalweather.asmx";

public String prova(String citta){
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather";
        final SoapObject requestObject=new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"GetWeather");   

        PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("CityName");
    pi.setValue(citta);
    pi.setType(String.class);
        requestObject.addProperty(pi);

  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        Marshal floatMarshal = new MarshalFloat();
        floatMarshal.register(envelope);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(requestObject);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport =  new HttpTransportSE(URL);
   androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
     String res="";

      try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        res=response.getPropertyAsString("Body");
     }catch(Exception e){Log.d("Prova",e.toString());}
     Log.d("Prova", res);
      return res;
 }
```

}

But I get this Exception : java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET";
```

should be `private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.com";`

and `final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetWeather";`
should be `final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.com/GetWeather";`

let me know if i am mistaken.